# Google Cloud Scheduler: Cost of required App Engine instance?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-scheduler

I would like to use google cloud scheduler to invoke a Google Cloud Run function on a routine schedule.

On [google cloud scheduler documentation](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs) it states:

> Cloud Scheduler is currently available in all App Engine supported
> regions. To use Cloud Scheduler your Cloud project must contain an App
> Engine app that is located in one of the supported regions. If your
> project does not have an App Engine app, you must create one.

I have never used app engine as a deployment target and don't really want to. This one cloud run function meets my needs.

Beyond the [stated costs of cloud scheduler pricing](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/pricing) will I also incur google app engine costs for a service I don't otherwise use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [definitely create](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/using-scheduler-invoke-private-functions-oidc) an scheduler job that runs your Cloud function on a timed interval.

However, App Engine needs to be **at least enabled** since Cloud scheduler requires it (see point 4 of the before you begin section):

> Cloud Scheduler uses App Engine cron jobs, so Cloud Scheduler requires App Engine enablement and configuration.

You would only need to set up the region of App Engine, not deploy an App Engine app which incurs costs.